# How to fit and check negative binomial distribution to counts data in R?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution, normal-distribution, binomial-coefficients

I have a sample which is distributed as such , say, `rnorm(300, mean=100, sd=10)` (The rnorm just used as a sample data). I want to fit a negative binomial to it (a) visually using ggplot2 or base R package 
(b) also run an appropriate test to check whether or not it is actually negative binomial (In this case it shouldn't). I am not sure how to achieve this in R.

So I tried this as an initial starting point (from this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205403/fitting-negative-binomial-distribution-to-large-count-data))

```
tt <- c(1:100)    
hist(tt, prob = TRUE)
library(fitdistrplus)
fit <- fitdist(data = tt, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")
fitD <- dnbinom(0:100, size=2.116252, mu=50.492772)
lines(fitD, lwd="3", col="blue")
```

However, this fits data to the probability density function. I want to fit it to a regular frequency distribution

Comment: So where exactly are you you getting stuck? What have you tried so far? Do you know how to do this in other languages than R?

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect where I am getting stuck. I don't know how to proceed from here on